# SQL Server & C#: How to save changes to date field after it has been converted to varchar format

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# WinForms app that receives a date field (Start_Date) from an MS SQl Server database that has been converted to a varchar (10) format before displaying it in a textbox in my app. I convert it to a varchar format so that the time portion doesn't show up when it's displayed in the textbox.  Even though Start_Date  is a date and not datetime data type in the database, the WinForms app textbox automatically adds the unwanted time portion which is why I have to convert it.

However, when I save changes to the date in that textbox, it will not write those changes back to the database (presumably because it was converted to a varchar format for display). How can I show the Start_Date field in the textbox with only the date portion and not the time component and still allow changes to be made to that date field and then saved back to the database.

Thank you.

Here's the code when I pull the data from the database:

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), Start_Date, 101) AS StartDate FROM Table1
```

Here's the code binding the Start_Date field to the textbox from a data table called dt:

```
txtStart_Date.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StartDate")
```

Comment: *Even though Start_Date is a date and not datetime data type in the database, the WinForms app textbox automatically adds the unwanted time portion* - so display its [`ToShortDateString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-7.0) rather than the default `ToString()`? *it will not write those changes back to the database (presumably because it was converted to a varchar format for display)* - no, it's because it's a calculated field which does not have any storage in the first place.

Comment: The correct way of doing it is to get the actual date and set text box display in the format you want. But then have the editor to save the all/any parts of date. The `Date` part of `DateTime` in c# is xx/xx/xxxx.00000000

Comment: To add to the above comment ^^ `DataBindingsCollection` has `Add(String, Object, String, Boolean, DataSourceUpdateMode, Object, String)` -- *"Creates a binding that binds the specified control property to the specified data member of the specified data source, optionally **enabling formatting with the specified format string**, propagating values to the data source based on the specified update setting, setting the property to the specified value when DBNull is returned from the data source, and adding the binding to the collection."*